# Jenkins pipeline - checkout to specific patchset returns to the head of master

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins pipeline - checkout to specific patchset returns to the head of master

I wrote stage in pipeline which checkout to specific patch set, but when i print

git log --oneline -10

I see that i found in the head of master

The pipeline is like this:

```
            steps {
            deleteDir()
            echo 'Pull patch from Gerrit'
            echo "gerrit branch: ${GERRIT_BRANCH}, gerrit refspec: ${GERRIT_REFSPEC}"
             checkout(
                [
                     $class: 'GitSCM',
                     branches: [[name: "${GERRIT_BRANCH}"]],
                     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                     extensions: [],
                     submoduleCfg: [],
                     userRemoteConfigs: [
                         [
                            credentialsId: '*****',
                            refspec: "${GERRIT_REFSPEC}",
                            url: 'ssh://****'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                )
        }
```

Comment: Please give more information. Such as your pipeline please!
But I assume that u forgot FETCH_HEAD step.